# Lubuntu cursor gone crazy

Tags: lubuntu, cursor

Back when the laptop ran windows10 the mouse started going crazy but I disabled the touchscreen drivers and the problem was solved there but since I changed to Lubuntu. I don't know what to do and I cant even type in the terminal because the mouse is being so crazy when I try typing in terminal it closes  since the mouse is crazy. When I google "how to disable touchscreen", it says that I need to type there so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Switch to tty: [FN] + CTRL + ALT + F3, you will get permanent console

Comment: We don't know your release of Lubuntu (is it a *legacy* & EOL system using LXDE, or *modern* using LXQt?) I can't cope with touchpads on some laptops (hands constantly wipe across it typing) thus I just disable the touchpad... but a starting point is your software stack (your base Ubuntu system reflected in the *year.month* of release) you didn't provide.